# on hiding some buttons(by user) inside android layout, buttons should appear symmetrical in proper order as stated -

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have a linear layout(vertical)
          inside it, I have 2 linear layouts (horizontal) both
I have place buttons inside the linear layouts like -

---

Button1 Botton2 Botton3

Button4 Botton5 Botton6

---

Users have the ability to hide these buttons according to their need & keep the buttons they want.

So, When Users hide the button the buttons get unaliged.
Although I am using **weight** to align the button horizontally.
Still, it looks weird and unsymmetrical when user hide some buttons
Eg.Hiding Button1 & Button3
Result I got -

---

```
       Button2
```

Button4 Button5 Button6

---

But, I *want* it like this -

---

Button2 Button4 Button5

Button6

---

Comment: Please update the post with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a unique `GridLayout` or something similar that have 3 columns for each row. In this way if you hide some items, others shift